# How to run Neo4j 3.0.6 multiple instances in a single machine using INEO

Tags: neo4j

How to run `Neo4j 3.0.6` multiple instances in a single machine using ineo?
How To change port number of `Neo4j 3.0.6` version and instance using ineo?

Comment: Please share the code that you have tried. So that it is easier to assist you on that.

Comment: i tried The following commands 
 ineo create -v 3.0.6 my_db  
 ineo set-port my_db 9494
 ineo set-port -v 3.0.6 my_db 9494
 ineo instances

Answer (score 0):

ineo is a third party solution, and based on its github repo it is not maintained recently. Btw, have you checked the Create an instance with a specific port section of its [README.md](https://github.com/cohesivestack/ineo)?

```
ineo create -p8486 my_db_test
```

Currently neo4j offers a similar solution for this instance handling, it is called Neo4j Desktop, and it can be downloaded from here: https://neo4j.com/download/other-releases/

If you use the native neo4j database, then you should change the following properties in neo4j.conf to be able to have more instance locally:

```
dbms.connector.bolt.listen_address
dbms.connector.http.listen_address
dbms.connector.https.listen_address
```

Comment: I am happy to help! If this answer really solved your issue, please mark it as accepted. Thank you!

Comment: Ineo is active again. The last version (1.1.0) has been released today. https://github.com/cohesivestack/ineo